Firebird SQL add empty rows in resultset
How to add empty rows in Firebird SQL Select resultset.
I can create Select, and the select resultset before add 12 empty rows.
1st probe:
select * from table where id like 'R%'
union all
select null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null from table

It is add a lot of empty rows (table all recordcount)
2nd probe:
select * from table where id like 'R-%'
union
select null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null from table
union
select null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null from table

It is only 1 blank rows.

Parts of union don't have to be selects from the same database. There is tale named RDB$DATABASE which has exactly one row.

The second produces only one row exactly because you use UNION instead of UNION ALL.

But why do you even want to add empty rows? It sounds a bit like an XY problem to be honest.

You can, as you tried, use two queries that both select from your table and use UNION ALL to combine their results. But then add FIRST x in the second query (which will generate "empty rows") to define the number of rows that should be added.
For example for 12 empty rows and a table with 3 columns:
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE 'R%'
UNION ALL
SELECT FIRST 12 null,null,null FROM test;

Note: This will work fine as long as your table has at least the number of rows you set as number of empty rows. Otherwise, you will get as many empty rows as the table contains rows. Reading your question, I have the impression your table will always have enough rows (because you write you get more emtpy rows than intended when not using FIRST as I showed).
If you're not sure if your table always has enough rows, but need the fix number of empty rows, rather query x times against the table RDB$DATABASE.
Of course, the prefered way to implement such tasks is to use your application rather than doing this in SQL.
See this demo

In your first query, you use UNION ALL, so duplicates are not eliminated, and because you select from table, you get as many blank rows as there are rows  in the table "table". In the second example, you use UNION, so duplicates are eliminated.
As user13964273 indicates in the comments, you could (or should) select against the table RDB$DATABASE which is guaranteed to have only one row. If you do that combined with UNION ALL, you can control the number of rows.
That said, wanting to add "empty" or all NULL rows to a query result is - in my opinion - a pretty odd requirement. Ask yourself if this is not better solved in your presentation layer.
